# I'm trying to split and remove unnecessary characters from a column using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

I'm trying to remove all the unnecessary words and characters from the values in this column. I want the rows to contain 'Entry level', 'Mid-Senior level' etc. Also is there anyway to translate the arabic to english or shall I use replace function?

df_africa.seniority_level.value_counts()

```
{'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}            1073
{'Seniority level': 'Mid-Senior level'}        695
{'Seniority level': 'Associate'}               481
{'Seniority level': 'Not Applicable'}          150
{'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مستوى متوسط الأقدمية'}     115
{'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مستوى المبتدئين'}           82
{'نوع التوظيف': 'دوام كامل'}                    73
{'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مساعد'}                     48
{'مستوى الأقدمية': 'غير مطبق'}                  42
{'Seniority level': 'Internship'}               39
{'Employment type': 'Contract'}                 21
{'Employment type': 'Full-time'}                 1



I've tried the split function but i couldn't get it to work properly.
```

Comment: need example for answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` or indeed `df.head().to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use this :

```
import ast

#Is there any non-latin letters?
m = ~df_africa["seniority_level"].str.contains("[A-Z]")
​
s = df_africa["seniority_level"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
df_africa["new_col"] = s.str["مستوى الأقدمية"].where(m, s.str["Seniority level"])
```

If you need to translate the words extracted, use [`deep-translator`](https://pypi.org/project/deep-translator/) :

```
#pip install -U deep-translator
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

df_africa["new_col (TRA)"] = (
                                df_africa["new_col"]
                                    .fillna("")
                                    .apply(lambda x: GoogleTranslator(source="arabic")
                                                       .translate(x)
                                                       .title())
                                    .replace("", None)
                              )
```

Even though I suggest you to use a custom dict using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to get the appropriate translation.

##### # Output :

`display(df_africa)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful to know the type of the 'seniority_level' column, but I'm just gonna assume the column is made up of literal strings (e.g. "{'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}")

Can translate all the text with this [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/#description) package, it piggybacks off google translate so use it while it lasts. Make sure to install version 4.0.0rc1.

```
$ pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

**translate**:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

def translate_to_english(words):
    for character in words:
        if ord(character) > 127:
            return translator.translate(words, dest="en").text
    return words

df_africa["new_seniority_level"] = df_africa["seniority_level"].map(lambda row: translate_to_english(row))
print(df_africa)
```

```
                               seniority_level                                new_seniority_level
0           {'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}                 {'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}
1      {'Seniority level': 'Mid-Senior level'}            {'Seniority level': 'Mid-Senior level'}
2             {'Seniority level': 'Associate'}                   {'Seniority level': 'Associate'}
3        {'Seniority level': 'Not Applicable'}              {'Seniority level': 'Not Applicable'}
4                {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مستوى متوسط الأقدمية'}  {'Seniority level': 'average level of seniority'}
5                    {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مستوى المبتدئين'}            {'Seniority level': 'beginners' level'}
6                          {'نوع التوظيف': 'دوام كامل'}                  {'Recruitment type': 'full time'}
7                          {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مساعد'}                   {'Seniority level': 'assistant'}
8                        {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'غير مطبق'}                  {'Senior level': 'unprecedented'}
9            {'Seniority level': 'Internship'}                  {'Seniority level': 'Internship'}
10             {'Employment type': 'Contract'}                    {'Employment type': 'Contract'}
11            {'Employment type': 'Full-time'}                   {'Employment type': 'Full-time'}
```

**then get the text you want:**

```
import re

df_africa["new_seniority_level"] = df_africa["new_seniority_level"].map(lambda row: re.match(r".+: '(.*)'", row).group(1))
print(df_africa)
```

```
                               seniority_level         new_seniority_level
0           {'Seniority level': 'Entry level'}                 Entry level
1      {'Seniority level': 'Mid-Senior level'}            Mid-Senior level
2             {'Seniority level': 'Associate'}                   Associate
3        {'Seniority level': 'Not Applicable'}              Not Applicable
4                {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مستوى متوسط الأقدمية'}  average level of seniority
5                    {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مستوى المبتدئين'}            beginners' level
6                         {'نوع التوظيف': 'دوام كامل'}                   full time
7                         {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'مساعد'}                   assistant
8                       {'مستوى الأقدمية': 'غير مطبق'}               unprecedented
9            {'Seniority level': 'Internship'}                  Internship
10             {'Employment type': 'Contract'}                    Contract
11            {'Employment type': 'Full-time'}                   Full-time
```

Look into official [google translate api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/python) if googletrans eventually breaks.